# Dumb it down for me: What is parsing?

Tags: java, parsing, scheme

Yesterday I asked about grammar, and today in Java, I am learning how to implement an algorithm for parsing the grammar, using tokens from the lexical analyzer that I finished.

For this question, I need a person to check my understanding.

Let's suppose given the Scheme grammar:

```
exp -> ( rest
     | #f
     | #t
     | ' exp
     | integer_constant
     | string_constant
     | identifier

rest -> )
     | exp+ [ . exp ] )
```

Would the following pseudo code be correct? I studied the recursive descent parser, and would need to make a parse tree for the interpreter by creating nodes of the parse tree.

```
 Node parseExp() {
      check to see if the token is left parenthesis
           if true, return a node for Cons (which is a non-terminating node in Scheme 
           parse tree) and call parseRest()
      else check to see if the token is #f
           if true, return a node for Boolean with stored value #f
      else check to see if the token is #t
           if true, return a node for Boolean with stored value #t
      else check to see if the token is quote
           if true, return a node for Quote and recursively call parseExp()
      else check to see if the token is integer_constant
           if true, return a node for Integer with stored value int
      else check to see if the token is string_constant
           if true, return a node for String with stored string value
      else check to see if the token is identifier
           if true, return a node for identifier with stored string value
      else
           print error message saying a Syntax error occured
           return null
 }

 Node parseRest() {
      check to see if the token is right parenthesis
           if true, return a node for Nil (which is a terminating () node in scheme 
           parse tree)
      else  // I am having difficulty trying to put this into an algorithm here
           call parseExp() for the first expression
           while (token does not equal right parenthesis) {
                getNextToken()
                if (token equals right parenthesis)
                     return a node for right parenthesis
                else if (token equals dot)
                     return a node for dot
                     getNextToken()
                     if (token equals right parenthesis)
                          print error message saying a Syntax error occurred
                          return null
                     else
                        call parseExp()
                else
                     parseExp() 
           }    
 }
```

If I have a wrong idea about it, please correct me. parseRest() is said to require a lookahead token for it to make a decision, could that be explained and probably a pseudo code example?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be easier to write a regular expression and test the input via `string.matches(...)`?

Comment: Sure it can be, but I am constructing a compiler for scheme in Java. It needs to be furnished with error checking. And next part after parsing is constructing the interpreter, which would require a data structure such as the parse tree.

Comment: @Hannes Java regular expressions don't support recursion and even if they did, writing such a monster regex would very likely not be easier than this (and definitely not more readable or maintainable). Generally parsing context-free languages with regular expressions is ill-advised (and not even possible in Java). And of course even if you had such a regex, it would not give you an AST, so all you could do is check for valid syntax, which isn't what we want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there's some issues:

```
check to see if the token is left parenthesis
     if true, return a node for Cons (which is a non-terminating node in Scheme 
     parse tree) and call parseRest()
```

This is a bit ambiguous since you don't mention what you intend to do with the result of `parseRest()`, but I assume you want to store it in the Cons node. The problem with that is that a Cons node should have two children (in case of a list that'd be the head of the list and its tail - if that isn't clear, you may have to review the rules of the Scheme language), yet parseRest only gives you one node, so that doesn't work. So let's take a step back and think about what we want when we see a `(`:

A `(` is either the start of a pair (i.e. a dotted pair or a non-empty list) or it's the empty list `()`. In the first case we want a Cons node, but in the second case we want a Nil node as an empty list is not a cons cell. So we have two possibilities and we don't know which one to choose until we've looked at the rest of the list. Therefore the decision shouldn't be made here, but rather inside the parseRest function. So we change the code to:

```
check to see if the token is left parenthesis
     if true, return the result of parseRest()
```

So now let's look at parseRest:

Here you sometimes returns nodes for dots and parentheses, but those aren't supposed to be nodes in the AST at all - they're tokens. Another issue is that when you call parseRest recursively, you again aren't clear about what you want to do with the result. One might think you want to return the result, but then your while-loop would be pointless since you return out of it right in the first iteration every time. In fact this is a problem even in the non-recursive cases: For example you return a dot node and then continue to parse the expression after it. But after the return the function exits, so anything that comes after the return will be ignored. So this doesn't work.

Before we talk about how to make it work, let's first get a clearer picture of what the generated AST is supposed to look like:

- For "()" we want a Nil node. That works fine with your current code.
- For "(x)" we want `Cons(Ident("x"), Nil)`.
- For "(x . y)" we want `Cons(Ident("x"), Ident("y"))`.
- For "(x y)" we want `Cons(Ident("x"), Cons (Ident("y"), Nil))`.
- For "(x y . z)" we want `Cons(Ident("x"), Cons (Ident("y"), Ident("z")))`.

I hope the pattern is now clear (else you might want to review the Scheme language). So how do we get that kind of AST?

Well, if we see a `)`, we return `Nil`. Again that already works in your code. Otherwise we parse an expression (and if there is no valid expression here, we have an error). Now what happens after that? Well if we found an expression, that expression is the first element of a Cons cell. So we want to return `Cons(theExpression, ...)`. But what goes into the `...` part? Well that depends on whether the next token is a dot or not. If it is a dot, we have a dotted expression, so there needs to be an expression after the dot and we want to return `Cons(theExpressionBeforeTheDot, theExpressionAfterTheDot)`. If there's no dot, it means we're in a list and what follows is its tail. So we want to return `Cons(theExpression, parseRest())`.

> parseRest() is said to require a lookahead token for it to make a decision, could that be explained and probably a pseudo code example?

Lookahead means that you have to look at the token that comes next without actually removing it from the stream. In terms of your pseudo code that means that you want to know which token will be returned when you call `nextToken()` without actually changing what the next call to `nextToken()` will return. So you'd have another built-in function like `peekNext()` that returned the next token without actually advancing the iterator in the token stream.

The reason why you need this in parseRest is the dot: When you check whether the next token is a dot and it turns out that it isn't, then you don't want the token to be actually gone. That is, you'll call parseExpression and then parseExpression will call nextToken, right? And when that happens you want it to return the token that comes right after the current expression - you don't want to skip that token because you had to check whether it's a dot. So when checking for the dot, you need to call `peekToken` instead of `nextToken` (you still need to remove the token when it is a dot though).

Comment: Wow, very helpful post! I will need to touch up on how dots work in scheme but other than that, it is clear for me. Thank you!

Comment: Got to come back and say this: this is really clear now, I know how to return a node now, it would be like return new Cons(car node, cdr node)! where the node could be either further parsing or a terminator.